# Microsoft Excel - Horizontal and Vertical Bars Missing

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

I don't know what I did, but the horizontal and vertical bars are missing in Microsoft 365.

How can I get them back? Is there a particular shortcut?

Comment: What bars? The scrollbars? The cell outlines? Something else? Please [edit] the question to be specific. An image showing your issue would also be good to add.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the scroll bar?
Did all Workbooks have this problem?
Try to go to *File*- *Options*- *Advanced*- *Display options for this workbook*- make sure these options are checked:

***1. Show horizontal scroll bar***

***2. Show Vertical scroll bar***

[image]